# Searching public comments containing a word during a period of time (range of date)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve all public comments with a/or more given words in the text during a specific period of time.
My query is like the following:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22Hello%22&since=2012-08-01&until=2012-08-20&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN
If you do not have an access token you can use the following link, without access_token:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22Hello%22&since=2012-08-01&until=2012-08-20

I can not get any results. If I omit the period of time, searching for a specific word, I get only few of the newest posts.

I read that I can only retrieve a period of max 35 days. My query is in that range.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Mauro

Comment: I can't follow your link.  Please include your code directly in your question.

Comment: Delete access_token part: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22Hello%22&since=2012-08-01&until=2012-08-20

Comment: Ummmmmm ***Please include your code directly in your question.***

Comment: Done. What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The public post search API only keeps a few days' of public posts, and isn't searchable by time.

The only supported search option in the docs is the query in the `q` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the piece of information.
In my understanding, nor facebook or linkedin or twitter have a good api for datamining purposes. That`s a pity.